# Call a field of a stdClass object by value in string variable

Tags: php, field, eval, stdclass

I have a name of an stdClass object that I'd like to call in string variable:

```
$field_title = "field_delivery_time['und']['0']['value']";
```

I would like to call this field, including its arrays and subarrays, of an object - something like this:

```
$object->"field_delivery_time['und']['0']['value']" = '10 days';
```

Is it possible to achieve it in PHP? Should I use eval() somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables as field accessors:

```
$object->$field_title = '10 days';
```